# should i return the pointers in the function so i can use them? example, should i return table2_entry?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

my struct looks like this:

```
struct table2
{
int k;
float value;
int row;
int col;
int nextK_row;
int nextK_col;
};
int allocate(int k, int n, struct table2 *table2_entry,struct table3 *table3_entry)
{
    //allocate memory to table2
table2_entry=(struct table2*)malloc((sizeof(struct table2))*k);
if(table2_entry==0)
{
    printf("Out of memory\n");
    return 1;
}
table3_entry=(struct table3*)malloc((sizeof(struct table3))*n);
if(table3_entry==0)
{
    printf("Out of memory\n");
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

if i do this in the main function:

```
for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
{
fscanf(source,"%d %f %d %d %d %d", &(table2_entry[i]).k,&(table2_entry[i]).value,&(table2_entry[i]).row,&(table2_entry[i]).col,&(table2_entry[i]).nextK_row,&(table2_entry[i]).nextK_col);
printf("%f\n",(table2_entry[i]).value);
}
```

would it work? or am i just overseeing anything? please please please help me. :(

Comment: So you call `allocate` function from main to allocate memory for structure right?

Comment: Short answer: No, it won't work. Both of those allocations are leaking outright and mean *nothing* to the *caller* of your `allocate()` function. You're allocating memory and assigning it to what are effectively two automatic variables. You need to pass your *pointers* by address (as pointers to pointers).

Answer (score 0):

In order for the callers of `allocate` to be able to use the memory allocated in it, you will have to change the function to look like:

```
int allocate(int k, int n,
             struct table2 **table2_entry,
             struct table3 **table3_entry)
{
   //allocate memory to table2
   *table2_entry=(struct table2*)malloc((sizeof(struct table2))*k);
   if(table2_entry==0)
   {
      printf("Out of memory\n");
      return 1;
   }

   *table3_entry=(struct table3*)malloc((sizeof(struct table3))*n);
   if(table3_entry==0)
   {
      printf("Out of memory\n");
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Then, in another function, one can call it like:

```
struct table2 *table2_entry = NULL;
struct table3 *table3_entry = NULL;
allocate(10, 3, &table2_entry, &tabl3_entry);
```

With the version you have, the memory allocated in `allocate` is a leak. The client code doesn't get it because pointers are passed by value.